# Usar Toastr sin usar el atributo onclick

Tags: javascript

Hace poco tenía Toastr llamándolo desde el atributo `onlick` en mi botón así:

```
<button onclick="toastr.info('Proceso correcto', 'Gracias!');">
```

Y en un archivo externo de JavaScript con este código:

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toastr-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": true,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "1100",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};
```

Pero leí que hacerlo de esa forma era una mala práctica, así que buscando [cómo reemplazarlo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655525/how-do-i-replace-onclick-with-a-better-alternative-in-vanilla-javascript) logré hacerlo de esta forma:

```
document.getElementById("terminado").addEventListener("click", toastnativo);
function toastnativo() {
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toastr-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": true,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "1100",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};
toastr.info('Proceso correcto', 'Gracias!');
}
```

Todo funciona bien, **pero quiero saber si lo estoy haciendo de la forma correcta** y si no supone algún problema para mi sitio.

Comment: Parece que esa librería depende de jQuery y puedes simplificar la asignación del evento: `$("#terminado").on("click", toastnativo);`

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Todo correcto, pero podrías simplificar la asignación del evento con `terminado.addEventListener("click", toastnativo)` ya que `terminado` es una variable autogenerada en el ámbito de `window` al ser el `id` de un elemento del DOM. Es decir, no es necesario hacer un `document.getElementById("terminado")` cuando estás en el ámbito de `window`, y si estás fuera de él puedes seguir accediendo a ese valor a través de `window.terminado` p `window["terminado"]`. Hacer uso de `$("#terminado")` es una sobrecarga de ejecución de código completamente innecesaria.

Comment: Además, si la asignación del atributo `options` va a ser siempre la misma, podrías hacerlo una única vez fuera del manipulador de eventos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque tu código es correcto, te aconsejo las siguientes mejoras:

- No es necesario llamar a `document.getElementById("terminado")` ni `$("#terminado")` ni similar para acceder a un elemento por su ID. Automáticamente se genera una variable con nombre igual al ID en el ámbito de `window` por cada elemento del DOM que tenga identificador, por lo que puedes usar simplemente `terminado`.
- Si vas a configurar siempre del mismo modo `Toastr` entonces es más eficiente hacerlo una única vez fuera del manipulador de eventos en vez de hacerlo cada vez que se genera el evento.
- Si no vas a reutilizar la función que muestra el bocadillo (toast) puedes hacer uso de una función anónima.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de las tres recomendaciones aplicadas:

```js
/* Configuramos Toastr una única vez */
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toastr-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": true,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "1100",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};

/* Agregamos el manipulador de eventos usando una función anónima */
terminado.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => toastr.info('Proceso correcto', '¡Gracias!')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js" integrity="sha512-VEd+nq25CkR676O+pLBnDW09R7VQX9Mdiij052gVCp5yVH3jGtH70Ho/UUv4mJDsEdTvqRCFZg0NKGiojGnUCw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.css" integrity="sha512-3pIirOrwegjM6erE5gPSwkUzO+3cTjpnV9lexlNZqvupR64iZBnOOTiiLPb9M36zpMScbmUNIcHUqKD47M719g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button id="terminado">Pulsar aquí</button>
```

---

El siguiente código:

```
() => toastr.info('Proceso correcto', '¡Gracias!')
```

Es equivalente al siguiente:

```
() => {
  return toastr.info('Proceso correcto', '¡Gracias!');
}
```

Que, a su vez, es equivalente a esto último:

```
function() {
  return toastr.info('Proceso correcto', '¡Gracias!');
}
```

Tener/usar o no el `return` es opcional y en este caso no afecta al funcionamiento de la página. Podría quitarse sin ningún problema y el código funcionaría igual, pero lo he dejado por simplificar y facilitar la lectura del código.

Si no te gusta usar un `return` o puede influir en el funcionamiento de la web, el código sin él sería:

```
() => { toastr.info('Proceso correcto', '¡Gracias!'); }
```

Comment: Excelente, no tenía idea del primer punto, muchísimas gracias por la explicación!